# How do particular skin layers show (de)hydration characteristics?

Tags: dermatology, hydration, dehydration, dry-skin, sensors

On the subject of health tracking and biosensors, in particular optical sensors such as *blood pressure*, *optical sensor* and *blood oxygen level*. Would an optical sensor theoretically be able to determine (de)hydration status?

I found this image showing the penetration of skin by different wavelengths.

[image: Skin penetration with different wavelengths]

Manual tests to check the skin elasticity as a sign of (dehydration) exist like:
[image: Skin turgor test]

Can a similar effect as shown on above test be seen on in a particular skin layer (when inspected using a specific wavelength)? In other words: **How do particular skin layers show (de)hydration characteristics?**

Comment: I count 9 questions in your question. Care to focus on one?

Comment: I already put a huge effort to limit it , that's why also "related side-questions". Main question: How do particular skin layers show (de)hydration characteristics?

Comment: A huge effort? I could limit it to your main question with 10 seconds of deleting text.

Comment: Ok, maybe not a huge effort. Done.

Comment: I don't think "could theoretically" questions are a very good fit for this site. Unlike, say, physics, "theoretically" questions in biology and medicine don't usually have any definitive answer. There's no equation to plug in and show you're outside the bounds of some known laws. We require answers to be supported with reliable sources, and no reliable source is going to be able to say "no" to a question like this because it's not possible for such a source to test the infinite possible solutions and rule them all out.

Comment: If such a device existed and you wanted to understand the biological concepts behind how it works, that would be a question that's a good fit for the site.

Comment: @BryanKrause then let it be hypothetical. I don't think the concept is far off current optical sensors (heart rate, blood pressure/oxygen). My question is "How do particular skin layers show (de)hydration characteristics?" that's a biological concept. If some characteristic or behavior related to (de)hydration are for example visible only one or in multiple skin layers, than theoretically it must be observable using those corresponding wavelengths. I'm not asking to invent the device here, I'm wondering what's theoretically even possible in regards to skin (layers) vs. (de)hydration status.

Comment: @Bob Substituting "hypothetical" for "theoretical" doesn't change anything about the issues I've raised, and your comment uses the word "theoretical" twice to describe what you're looking for. Your question does not show any research effort into the area of dyhydration and the skin to constrain or focus an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the article "**Review of Advances in the Measurement of Skin Hydration Based on Sensing of Optical and Electrical Tissue Properties**": https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/22/19/7151.

> **Abstract**: The presence of water in the skin is crucial for maintaining the properties and functions of the skin, in particular its outermost layer, known as the stratum corneum, which consists of a lipid barrier. ... Furthermore, the exploration of optical techniques to measure hydration is growing due to the outcomes observed through the penetration of light at differing levels. *This paper comprehensively reviews such measurement techniques, focusing on recent experimental studies and state-of-the-art devices.*

> Optical imaging uses light to obtain and investigate images for medical applications. These images are typically produced within the ultraviolet to near-infrared wavelength region.

> Near-infrared spectroscopy (NIRS) covers the **780–2500 nm wavelength** region of the electromagnetic spectrum and provides **information on the perfusion of tissues**.

> There are different optical techniques that have, more recently, been **used to investigate the hydration levels** of the skin. Some include confocal Raman spectroscopy, optical coherence tomography, speckle patterns analysis using optical tissue probing and optoacoustic monitoring. Another technique is near-infrared spectroscopy, which will later be discussed in more detail.

Comment: I don't think this answers your question. It's research that belongs in your question.